# Akka Streams - Split incoming sources data based on some predicate

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm newbie in Akka Streams framework and I want to know the possibilities to solve my problem with aim of Akka Streams.
Imagine here is a problem:

1. Several large iteratee sources, e.g. 3-4 large files with probably
   the same data;
2. Each file needs to be processed: parsed, transformed,
   average value calculated;
3. Data from file should be partitioned by
   some predicate and then processed by partition. Partition predicate can be  dynamic from run to run;
4. Every partition should be saved
   to another file or stream, or so.

Is it possible to solve with Akka Streams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using [Partition](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.46923239.1579561034.1353497989#akka.stream.scaladsl.Partition)?

Answer (score 0):

As Victor says, Partition will do this for you. I found an example in the Akka unit tests:

```
 val (s1, s2, s3) = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(Sink.seq[Int], Sink.seq[Int], Sink.seq[Int])(Tuple3.apply) { implicit b ⇒ (sink1, sink2, sink3) ⇒
        val partition = b.add(Partition[Int](3, {
          case g if (g > 3)  ⇒ 0
          case l if (l < 3)  ⇒ 1
          case e if (e == 3) ⇒ 2
        }))
        Source(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) ~> partition.in
        partition.out(0) ~> sink1.in
        partition.out(1) ~> sink2.in
        partition.out(2) ~> sink3.in
        ClosedShape
      }).run()
```